# Nodejs Async/Await in api controller responds with unknown error

Tags: node.js, async-await

```
export function getAllHost(req, res) {
    function findAllHost() {
        let query = {};

        query.company = req.query && req.query.companyId ? req.query.companyId : res.locals.payload.companyId;
        query.active = true;

        if(req.query && req.query.name) {
            let regexp = new RegExp('\\b' + req.query.name);
            query['name'] = {$regex: regexp, $options: 'i'};
        }

        return Host.find(query);
    }

    async function sendRes() {
        let allHost = [];
        let hosts = [];
        try {
                hosts = await findAllHost();
        } catch(err){
                console.log(err)
        }
        for (let host of hosts) {
            allHost.push(new Host_V1(host));
        }
        return allHost
    }

    sendRes().then(data => res.status(200).json(data)).catch(error => {
        console.log("error is", error);
        res.status(error.status || 500).json({
            message: error.status ? error.message : 'Server Error'
        });
    });
}
```

I have been trying to adapt async/await into my code, so I converted one of the `Promise` based api controller to make use of `async/await`, but the thing that bothers me is that my server responds with 500, and the `console.log` inside my catch block doesn't print anything.

No error gets thrown.

I am using babel `babel-plugin-syntax-async-functions` to parse it.

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a bit overcomplicated, but judging by it you should receive an error in the console if one appears. It could instead be that you have a middleware producing an error? The main issue is that you're catching the error in the async function `sendRes`, so the `.catch`-method you call on the returned Promise will never be fired even if there is an error.
Like many others that are new to `async/await`, you've misunderstood and believe that you *have* to wrap every `await` expression in a `try/catch`-block. This is not the case. The error "trickles" up the call chain, and unless a particular function can provide a different return value, it's best to catch the error from the top-most callee. Take this simple example which shows a common anti-pattern: https://repl.it/repls/PunySafeInterfacestandard (await and async isn't even needed in these examples, but I added them for clarity)

But if you try to simplify your code, maybe something like the below snippet, you might be able to rule out if it's a middleware or not.

```
export async function getAllHosts (req, res) {
  try {
    let query = {
      company: req.query && req.query.companyId ? req.query.companyId : res.locals.payload.companyId,
      active: true
    }

    if (req.query && req.query.name) {
      let regexp = new RegExp('\\b' + req.query.name)
      query.name = {$regex: regexp, $options: 'i'}
    }

    let allHosts = (await Host.find(query)).map((host) => new Host_V1(host))
    return res.json(allHosts)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("error is", e)
    res.status(error.status || 500).json({
      message: error.status ? error.message : 'Server Error'
    })
  }
}
```

Take note of the `(await Host.find(query))` line. If the Promise that's returned from `Host.find()` rejects, the `.map()`-method won't be executed on the data and execution will jump to the `catch`-block.

I also heavily discourage using Babel since `async/await` has been natively supported in Node since version 7.6.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your post. I forgot to mention. I did try a similar method, but I kept getting error, regeneratorRuntime is not defined, and I tried building my code with and without the bale async plugin, I kept getting the same error.

Comment: What version of Node do you use? `regeneratorRuntime` is part of Babel. If you use a Node version above or equal to 7.6, you shouldn't need Babel for `async/await`.

Comment: I am using 8.9.4, and we require babel for `import` and `export` statements. I have been trying to find a way to make babel ignore a specific feature.

Comment: Ah, I understand. In that case you can uninstall the `babel-plugin-syntax-async-functions` plugin and only use the `babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs` plugin instead. Since your version of Node already has native support for `async/await`, it makes very little sense to transform it into ES5 JavaScript. Either way, the above code should work and it may indeed be a middleware producing a non-existant error.

Comment: Hey, thanks for an important lead. Currently, I am using babel's `env` preset, and if I remove it, and add commonjs module, then it's failing to do the expected job, all my exports get resolved to [Object undefined]. But I'll look into it.

Comment: Hey, I found out the solution. I need to use this plugin https://github.com/59naga/babel-plugin-add-module-exports along with commonjs plugin. Thanks for your direction. Kindly, add this extra info to your answer, so that other people can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : The value returned is indeed a promise

<del>I think that the error is related to your 'SendRes.then' since what SendRes returns *is not* a promise but it's actually is the Array allHost</del>

<del>Your data argument is not an argument anymore it is the value returned from the sendRes function thanks to your async / await implementation.</del>

```
const hosts = sendRes();
res.status(200).json(hosts);
```

<del>if you want to handle an error you must return something from your catch block so that you can can handle it here.</del>

```
if (!hosts) res.status(500);
```

<del>To simplify your code you can also get rid of the sendRes function and make your getAllHost express middleware an async function</del>

```
async getAllHost(req, res) { /*...*/ }

try {
    let allHosts = await findAllHosts();
    res.status(200).json(allHosts);
} catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send({ error })
}
```

Comment: `async` functions *always* returns a `Promise`, so the `SendRes` function does return a Promise that resolves to the returned value.

Comment: Indeed but it seems to me that its async function returns the allHost variable which is an Array

Comment: It doesn't matter what is returned, under the hood the JavaScript engine (V8 in this case) will wrap it in a Promise, which resolves when the `return` statement is successfully executed, or rejects when anything in the function call chain `throw`s or returns a Promise that rejects.

Comment: @MaieonBrix Hey, thanks for your post, but that's not correct. Async wraps the value returned from that function in `Promise.resolve`. So that's not an issue.